# How to change stroke width of line in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path

I have drawn some lines with the line tool in Photoshop CS6.

The lines are vectors on a shape layer.

If I select the line with path selection tool I can change the stroke colour, in the options panel at the top, but not the stroke width (if I change the stroke width nothing happens).

Is there a way to change the stroke width?

Comment: It's pretty annoying. It's more reliable if you press enter or tab after each time you enter a value.

Comment: @Joonas nope that's not it

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the problem you have is that your lines are set to stroke 'inside' so no matter what the pt weight you wont see a result. You need to click the line style next to the pt weight > then more options > then where it says align, set to center or outside. Hope that helps.

Mark[image: example]

Comment: Hey Mark (nice name!). Welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: This is the most relevant answer that I've seen from the 3 here.  You need to set your stroke to the OUTSIDE of your shape.  PS defaults it to an inner stroke, not an outer stroke, so no matter how thick you make it, it's obviously not going to show up, if it's set to "inner stroke"

Comment: this is the solution so I've accepted it. I also upvoted @Ryan's answer because he correctly identifies the underlying problem: for some bizarre reason a 'line' is actually drawn as a rectangle by Photoshop. if it was a real line there could not be any 'inner' vs 'outer' stroke

Comment: BTW ...it's really __center__ stroke option that's needed here... an 'outside' stroke will have a hole in the middle where the 'line' itself is

Answer (score 10):

This has confused me many times because I think and want it to be stroke path but its not.

What you actually want in Photoshop with the `Line` tool is **Weight**.

[image: Line Weight]

However, once a `Line` is created in Photoshop it acts as a `Rectangular Shape` so the `Weight` can no longer be changed by adjusting the numeric value.

Now, `Stroke Width` will in fact apply a **Stroke** around the `Line`, because again a `Line` in Photoshop is basically a `Rectangular Shape`. This is a 40px WEIGHT line with a 3pt stroke around it:

[image: stroked line]

Comment: +1, the key insight here is that the Line tool in Photoshop actually just draws long, skinny _rectangles_

Comment: How do you display that bar of tools after drawing the line?